# Using :before in input field

Tags: html, css

I want to add some content before the first input field in the following markup using the `:before`. The reason of using :before is that the markup cannot be changed.

I'm trying this, but does not work:

**HTML:**

```
<p class="submit">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Post" name="submit">
    <input id="" type="hidden" value="" name="">
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.submit input:before{
    content:"Test ";
}
```

This would work, but I want to place the content inside .submit:

```
.submit:before{
    content:"Test ";
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gb2wY/

Comment: `:before` is supposed to be rendered as a new first _child_ element for the element it is applied to – but input field can not _have_ child elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field

Comment: Cleanest thing to do is to use a label as a wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/gb2wY/2/

Comment: You can do it using jquery .before http://jsbin.com/iVefeso/1

Comment: @CBroe Except for when they can http://oi65.tinypic.com/r253wp.jpg

Comment: @NathanHornby: Some browser have chosen to implement it for such elements as well, yes. But that must not necessarily mean it will work everywhere.

Comment: @CBroe Definitely, I think some consistency is required there - seems pretty arbitrary. But importantly "…input field can not have child elements" is a false statement; as sometimes they can.

Comment: @NathanHornby: Well in HTML they can not have child elements. And if you combine that with what the CSS spec (2.1) says about pseudo elements, _“The :before and :after pseudo-elements interact with other boxes as if they were real elements inserted just inside their associated element”_ you have the argument for why one should not rely on that working properly in all browsers.

Comment: @CBroe This is clearly a semantics disagreement - ultimately some self-closing elements can contain pseudo elements, even thought the spec says they *shouldn't*. But, sometimes they definitely can. I just thought it was worth clarifying for future visitors.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can do this as `input` has no content to put the pseudo-element before.

You could use the `button` element instead.

Comment: Except for the `date`input field, apparently (at least in Chrome). I've just run into this issue, where the date field will accept pseudo elements, but a number field won't.